# azure devops server workspace set up

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

I am currently working on a project with another person and trying to setup Azure devops to make it easier for us to keep track of the application. So far what we would like to do is set it up so we can both create a server workspace and each work on the application therefore when we checkout a file the other person will know that the other person is working on it and vice versa. however upon setting it up when I try and download the project C# .net web application I keep getting the errors that Access to path to certain folders is denied, and when checking properties its all read only but the other person is able to perfectly fine to open it even though its read-only. Any thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated it thanks.

created server workspace on my account and download files from server but when downloaded all files were view only and when tried to build application getting errors access to path is denied, however other user was able to build perfectly fine with exact same steps.

Comment: Can you describe in detail what you mean by "when I try and download the project C# .net web application I keep getting the errors that Access to path to certain folders is denied"? How did you download it? Where did you see the error message? Can you share some screenshots to help understand your question?